# Where/when to implement replications in bootstrapping?

Tags: bootstrap, simulation, item-response-theory

I have a dataset of people who completed a computer adaptive test (CAT), and calculated a person fit statistic for each examinee. Since the distribution of the statistic is unknown, I want to use a bootstrap procedure to approximate the sampling distribution of the 95th quantile, based on a number of resamples, in order to get a cut off to flag "high" (i.e. "bad") person fit scores.

So, I simulated $N$=1000 examinees with $\theta$ from distribution $N(0,1)$, ran the CAT, calculated the fit statistic (vector $Y$ of length $N$), performed the bootstrapping procedure and took the median as the cut off score. However, as I simulate a different set of 1000 examinees and repeat this procedure, I (naturally) arrive at a somewhat different cut off score. I want to arrive at a "best estimate" of the cut off score, which in my eyes implies replications and then taking the mean. My question is: when to replicate? And when do I take the mean?

Do I repeat the above procedure $R$ times and then take the mean of the outcomes as my cut off (seems odd, taking the mean of the medians)? 
Or do I simulate a new set of examinees $R$ times, "save" vector $Y$ each time (creating an $R * Y$ matrix), take the mean over the columns (creating a new vector $Z$, i.e. "mean fit statistic over $R$ replications", of length $N$) and then perform the bootstrapping procedure?

Or are there other/better alternatives?

Comment: Yes it is to be expected, as you say, that your bootstrapped 95th percentile will change from one N=1000 sample to another, but "in real life" you only have one sample of N and can only increase the number of bootstrap replications to get a more accurate estimate of the 95th percentile. Whilst you can can take the average of many bootstrapped 95th percentile estimates, I would imagine the "best" estimate would be obtained with N being a very large number and performing a single bootstrap on that - i.e. when you have "infinite" sample size